# How to check the underlying hardware information on an AWS EC2 box

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I wanted to check the description of an EC2 instance hardware description.
For example, its RAM

dmidecode shows empty infortmation

```
sudo dmidecode --type 17
# dmidecode 3.0
Getting SMBIOS data from sysfs.
SMBIOS 2.7 present.
```

'lshw -c memory' does not show much details...

```
lshw -c memory
  *-firmware
       description: BIOS
       vendor: Amazon EC2
       physical id: 0
       version: 1.0
       date: 10/16/2017
       size: 64KiB
       capabilities: pci edd acpi virtualmachine
  *-memory
       description: System memory
       physical id: 1
       size: 68GiB
```

Is this because on AWS, the memory is an abstraction of some real hardware?

However, for CPU, it seems available at /proc/cpuinfo

Answer (score 1):

Here is the list of 16 commands:

https://www.binarytides.com/linux-commands-hardware-info/

You can try any to these to get the specific information you are trying to get.